# Selectbox option on click of image

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I got a plugin that generates extra options for products (woocommerce).

1. I create selectbox with few options like: blackky, whiteey, greyyy
2. Then I create radio buttons with images: blackk, whitee, greyy

How can I 'connect it' so if someone clicks on 'blackk' it also select 'blackyy' option in selectbox.

Links how it looks:

https://dobrzekupuj.pl/product/woo-album-1/

https://dobrzekupuj.pl/product/woo-album-2/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: After selecting from the dropdown. Add a `tc-active` in the <li> and put the element in a variable so when you choose another option, you can remove the tc-active class in the previous element and put it in the new selected option.

Comment: I assume you known the basics, you should be fine with this example. Good luck: https://jsfiddle.net/1cujfwq3/5/

Comment: @JensIngels thank you for assistance, it works awesome but there is one issue:
- My select name it's changing e.g  tmcp_select_1 tmcp_select_2 (...)
- The same problem is with input type, name tmcp_radio_1, tmcp_radio_2 (...)
https://codepen.io/alicee11/pen/gOOZwQM

Comment: @Alicja It's because you don't refer to the elements correctly. Your inputList variable refers to all input elements within your code. I recommand coding an "IF" that detects what select is currently active and than generate the list based on that result.

Comment: Since where working with input the best solution would probally be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dq5wLpvu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Your values are not easy to parse

```js
$("[name=tmcp_radio_1]").on("click",function() {
  var val = this.value
  if (val) $("#tmcp_select_1").val(val.split("_")[0]+"ey_1")
})

$("#tmcp_select_1").on("change",function() {
  var val = this.value
  if (val) $("[name=tmcp_radio_1][value="+val.split("y_")[0]+"_1]").click()
})
```

Comment: I just what started learning js but maybe If the name of selectbox and image alt will be the same it would be easier?

https://codepen.io/alicee11/pen/rNNoxaY